# How to stop recording in android?

Tags: android, recording

i have this method,

```
    if(null != recorder){
      recorder.stop();
      recorder.reset();
      recorder.release();
      recorder = null;
    }
```

why it force closes my application?..

Thanks in advance!

this is my VoiceRecording2.java.. It has there buttons, start button and stop button and choose format..

```
 package com.example.voicexml;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.media.MediaRecorder;
  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class VoiceRecording2 extends Activity {
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP = ".3gp";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 = ".mp4";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";

    private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
    private int currentFormat = 0;
    private int output_formats[] = { MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4, MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP };
    private String file_exts[] = { AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4, AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP }; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voice);

    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);
    setFormatButtonCaption();
}

    private void setButtonHandlers() {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFormat)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }

    private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
            ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
    }

    private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
            enableButton(R.id.btnStart,!isRecording);
            enableButton(R.id.btnFormat,!isRecording);
            enableButton(R.id.btnStop,isRecording);
    }

    private void setFormatButtonCaption(){
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFormat)).setText(getString(R.string.audio_format) + " (" + file_exts[currentFormat] + ")");
    }

    private String getFilename(){
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

            if(!file.exists()){
                    file.mkdirs();
            }

            return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + file_exts[currentFormat]);
    }

    private void startRecording(){
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();

            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());

            recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
            recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

            try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private void stopRecording(){

    }

    private void displayFormatDialog(){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            String formats[] = {"MPEG 4", "3GPP"};

            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.choose_format_title))
                       .setSingleChoiceItems(formats, currentFormat, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    currentFormat = which;
                                    setFormatButtonCaption();

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                       })
                       .show();
    }

    private MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    AppLog.logString("Error: " + what + ", " + extra);
            }
    };

    private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    AppLog.logString("Warning: " + what + ", " + extra);
            }
    };

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch(v.getId()){
                            case R.id.btnStart:{
                                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                                    enableButtons(true);
                                    startRecording();

                                    break;
                            }
                            case R.id.btnStop:{
                                if(null != recorder){
                                    //recorder.stop();
                                    //recorder.reset();
                                    //recorder.release();
                                    System.out.println("Churva");
                                    //recorder = null;
                            }
                                AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                                    enableButtons(false);

                                    //stopRecording();

                                    break;
                            }
                            case R.id.btnFormat:{
                                    displayFormatDialog();

                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
    };
```

}

it a simple porgram that records a voice in your android device..

Comment: Please post the logcat output

Comment: Please share some more code and which class instance is this recorder of?

Comment: i posted the whole VoiceRecording2.java, it has also AppLog.java, and the layout..

Comment: post the logcat showing the error...

Comment: crash is occurring because of selecting output source to 3GPP or MPEG 4?

Comment: no, errorlog says stop called in an invalid state:4

Answer (score 1):

Check the Java text of `stop()` method of recorder which says:

> {`public void stop ()`  Since: API Level 1  Stops recording. Call this
>    after `start()`. Once recording is stopped, you will have to configure
>    it again as if it has just been constructed.
>
> Note that a
>    `RuntimeException` is intentionally thrown to the application, if no
>    valid audio/video data has been received when `stop()` is called. This
>    happens if `stop()` is called immediately after `start()`. The failure
>    lets the application take action accordingly to clean up the output
>    file (delete the output file, for instance), since the output file is
>    not properly constructed when this happens.
>
> Throws `IllegalStateException`  if it is called before `start()`}

So may be exception is arising due to no valid audio/video data has been received when `stop()` method is called.

Comment: I believe its force closing because the audio is not being processed properly in the audio file. Please do some googling to process audio file in particular extension in android may be that may help you. mean while you can add try catch to stopping recorder so that app should not crash

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a new instance of the MediaRecorder class (android.media.MediaRecorder)

```
MediaRecorder mr = new MediaRecorder();
```

Next, set the audio source or the recording device. Usually, you will want to set it to MIC

```
mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

Now specify the output format. This is the audio format the recorded file will be stored in.

```
mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

Also specify the AudioEncoder type

```
mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Finally, specify the file name where the recorded data will be stored. The Path name is the full path to the audio file.

```
mr.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
```

Now, the whole setup is complete. You just need to prepare the instance by calling `prepare()` and call the `start()` and `stop()` functions to start / stop recording.

```
mr.prepare();mr.start();.......mr.stop();
```

Once the recording is finished, you can release the resources associated with that particular instance by calling

```
mr.release();
```

You can also reset the MediaRecorder instance to the initial state by calling

```
mr.reset();
```

Optionally, you can also use `mr.setMaxDuration()` to set the maximum duration of the recording and `mr.setMaxFileSize()` to set the maximum file size used for recording.

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO">` in your Manifest